# update user model from some other control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, update-attribute

I have a user model. i want to update a column of user from some other controller, that is not related to user. following is my code to update value.

```
   def update
        @admin=current_user
        if @admin.update_attribute(:allow, params[:user][:allow])
          flash[:success] = "Feature updated"
          redirect_to '/recalls'
        else
            flash[:success]=@admin.errors.full_messages
        end
   end
```

the problem is allow value in db gets updated. i can verify it from my rails console. but while redirecting to `/recalls`, it log out and redirects to Login. 
i don't know what wrong i have done. plz let me know. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Gopalrathore  no, sir. i am not using devise or anything.

Comment: plz dont call me sir, and if u have sign_in method then u can call it with required attributes before redirecting to a location, It will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Gopalrathore i have sign_in method and by calling this has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment of Gopal Rathore in original post.
I added `sign_in` method as follows to solve the problem

```
   def update
        @admin=current_user
        if @admin.update_attribute(:allow, params[:user][:allow])
          sign_in
          flash[:success] = "Feature updated"
          redirect_to '/recalls'
        else
            flash[:success]=@admin.errors.full_messages
        end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue..  Solved this issue by some thing like this

```
@admin=User.find current_user.id
```

Please try this.. not sure this will work in your case..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it didn't worked for me. but i resolved my problem with the help of Gopal rathore's comment in original post. Well thanks again :)